# How to access local file in my chrome application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems

i writing Chrome application which work with local files, local links stored in indexedbd.

My logic:

1. Save local links in bd;
2. Get local links from indexedBD.
3. Upload file to fileSystem by local link.
4. Use file from fileSystem for any purpose.

The following code is not work:

```
window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1204, function(fileSystem) {
 fs = fileSystem;
 cwd = fs.root;
 //renderImages(cwd);
}, onError);

fs.root.getFile('C:\Images\Test\cat.jpg', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function (fileEntry) {
   if (fileEntry.isFile === true) {
     $("#myimage").attr("src", fileEntry.toURL());
   }
});


$("#myimage").attr("src", fileEntry.fullpath);
Error: GET chrome-extension://acnoddeoamaikpmmdkehnkppmcgcpfjl/C:ImagesTestcat.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestFileSystem` creates a virtual, sandboxed file system for your use, but you can't access local files through it. The filesystem you request is basically empty at creation time.

A Chrome Extension cannot access local files in principle, though a [native host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) can bypass that.

A Chrome App can use [`fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) to request access to parts of the local file system. You can "retain" entries and save them in your DB for later reuse.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t access local files,this will be a big security threat to user's computer,you can use browser local storage or cookie storage etc.